# Python на MacOS

Tags: python, macos

Пишу код из курса обучения следующего содержания:

```
# coding: utf-8
import turtle
turtle.circle(20)

answer = ''

while answer != 'N':
answer = turtle.textinput("Нарисовать окружность", "Y/N")
if answer == 'Y':
turtle.circle(30)
else:
pass
```

И вот если начать его запускать через сшел на маке, он пролетает без тормозов, модальное окно вопроса не выводит совсем, когда на винде все норм работает.

Как заставить его отрабатывать нормально на маке?

Comment: У вас код в вопросе сломан, поправьте, пожалуйста, отступы. А попробуйте этот код: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/paint%20with%20turtle/example.py . Он должен и у вас работать

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что у вас происходило закрытие окна приложения из-за отсутствия бесконечного цикла обработки событий, который нужно было вызывать через `turtle.done()`:

```
import turtle
turtle.circle(20)

answer = ''

while answer != 'N':
    answer = turtle.textinput("Нарисовать окружность", "Y/N")
    if answer == 'Y':
        turtle.circle(30)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек!!!!!!!!!!! Заработало окно!!!!!

Comment: @AndreySeregin, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)